# Why is my document entirely right-aligned?

Tags: margins

I usually don't spend too much time on formatting of LaTeX documents, so this is probably easy and I apologize.  I've changed my document from a twocolumn class to a onecolumn class, and all of a sudden my document is right-aligned, making many of the tables run off the page.  As an example, this is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Why is it doing that?  Here is my code at the top of my document:

```
\documentclass[times, 10pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{latex12}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,letterpaper=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
```

Thanks for any help

*Edit*:  The contents of latex12.sty:

```
\typeout{IEEE 8.5 x 11-Inch Proceedings Style `latex8.sty'.}
\font\tenhv  = phvb7t at 10pt
\font\elvbf  = cmbx10 scaled 1100

\setlength{\textheight}{8.875in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.375in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{1pc}

\def\@maketitle
   {
   \newpage
   \null
   \vskip .375in
   \begin{center}
      {\Large \bf \@title \par}
      % additional two empty lines at the end of the title
      \vspace*{24pt}
      {
      \large
      \lineskip .5em
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
         \@author
      \end{tabular}
      \par
      }
      % additional small space at the end of the author name
      \vskip .5em
      {
       \large
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
         \@affiliation
      \end{tabular}
      \par
      \ifx \@empty \@email
      \else
         \begin{tabular}{r@{~}l}
            E-mail: & {\tt \@email}
         \end{tabular}
         \par
      \fi
      }
      % additional empty line at the end of the title block
      \vspace*{12pt}
   \end{center}
   }

\def\abstract
   {%
   \centerline{\large\bf Abstract}%
   \vspace*{12pt}%
   \it%
   }

\def\endabstract
   {
   % additional empty line at the end of the abstract
   \vspace*{12pt}
   }

\def\affiliation#1{\gdef\@affiliation{#1}} \gdef\@affiliation{}

\def\email#1{\gdef\@email{#1}}
\gdef\@email{}

\newlength{\@ctmp}
\newlength{\@figindent}
\setlength{\@figindent}{1pc}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{
   \vskip 10pt
   \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\tenhv\noindent #1.~#2}
   \setlength{\@ctmp}{\hsize}
   \addtolength{\@ctmp}{-\@figindent}\addtolength{\@ctmp}{-\@figindent}
   % IF longer than one indented paragraph line
   \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\@ctmp
      % THEN set as an indented paragraph
      \begin{list}{}{\leftmargin\@figindent \rightmargin\leftmargin}
         \item[]\tenhv #1.~#2\par
      \end{list}
   \else
      % ELSE center
      \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}
   \fi}

\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
   {14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt} {\large\bf}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
   {13pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{13pt plus 2pt minus 2pt} {\fontsize{11}{\f@baselineskip}\bf}}%\elvbf}}
```

Comment: We need to see the contents of file `latex12.sty`; most probably it contains some declarations responsible for the mentioned layout.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ah!  Hadn't even thought of that... I'll add it now.  _Edit_ Added

Comment: Please make a _complete_ (small) document that shows the effect and remove all the packages that you can remove while still having the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This part of `latex12.sty`

```
\setlength{\textheight}{8.875in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.375in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
```

changes the default page layout, and in particular, the line

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
```

will produce the undesired layout. You can change the value `6.5in` to a more convenient value or, better yet, load the `geometry` package and use its `\geometry` command to change the page layout according to your needs. As an example, you could say something like:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2cm}
```

or

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=6.5in}
```

if you want to keep the original width for the text area. Make sure that the `\geometry` line appears *after* the `latex12` package has been loaded, and refer to the documentation of the `geometry` package to see all the options it offers.

A little example using `\geometry` to override the `latex12.sty` settings:

```
\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{latex12}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=6.5in}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

produces a two page document; the first page obtained (illustrating the resulting layout):

[image]

Comment: Got it, thanks!  Didn't know about the geometry package, good resource

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `latex12.sty` is a modification of `latex8.sty` (which was a style to mimic IEEE conference paper specifications).

The layout specifications of `latex8.sty` contain

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.304in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.304in}
```

which are not in `latex12.sty`.

An alternative package for IEEE conference papers is `IEEEconf.cls`.